# Google cloud SQL, total frequency ends with '00'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am currently trying to write a query to list all the male names of people born before 2000, where the total frequency of names ends with '00' such as "100, 200....".

I currently have:

```
SELECT name, SUM(count) as freq 
FROM names.names_database 
WHERE gender = 'M' AND year < 2000
Group by name;
```

I am unsure of how to find the total frequency ending with '00'.
any helpful information on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search the Internet for the SQL reserved word _having_. After the `Group by` in your query you need to add `having SUM(count) ...` See if you can figure out what needs to be written in place of the `...`

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT name, SUM(count) as freq 
FROM names.names_database 
WHERE gender = 'M' AND year < 2000
Group by name
HAVING MOD(freq, 100) = 0
```